# Window re-size event breaks toggle after resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with the below code.  I created a window re-size event for a toggle div.  The purpose is so when on smaller devices the header will toggle the content, otherwise the content is just displayed as is. The issue I am having is when I refresh the page, it works perfect.  The second I resize it and click to toggle, it causes some sort of recursive call 5 times, so it toggles back and forth 5 times.  Any suggestions?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
  $(".toggle" ).show();
}
else {
  $(".toggle" ).hide();

      $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle();
  });
}

}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommendable to insert a click function inside a resize function, because you are adding click functions to the tag every time you resize. If you add an unbind to the "opener" before the click line it should work.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() > 767) {
   $(".toggle" ).show();
}
else {
   $(".toggle" ).hide();
   $( ".opener" ).unbind("click");  
   $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
     $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle();
   });
}

}).resize();
```

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you so much.  So I understand, how exactly did that correct the issue?

Comment: Each time you do a resize you are adding the same function to the element, so for example if you do a resize 5 times, then the function will get called 5 times. The "unbind" what does is to remove all the attached event handlers it had before, it's like cleaning it before you add the function so it only triggers once this time.